# Is there a PHP security exploit with $_POST in my code?

Tags: php, sql, security

I posted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620423/creating-dynamic-tables-with-mysqli-securely).

And an answer stated that I should **not** do:

```
$table_name = 'survey_'.$_POST['surveyid'];
```

because

> It is easy for a hacker to exploit your site if you include `$_GET` or `$_POST` data directly in any SQL string.

Here is the code.  Do you see any security exploits?

```
if(ctype_digit($_POST['surveyid']) && $_POST['surveyid']>0){

    $table_name = 'survey_'.$_POST['surveyid'];

    $query = 'CREATE TABLE '.$table_name.' (
            `responseid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `textarea1` TEXT NULL,
            `textarea2` TEXT NULL,
            `textarea3` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
            `drop_down1` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
            `drop_down2` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
            `bool1` BIT NULL,
            `bool2` BIT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`responseid`))';
}
```

I don't see a vulnerability.... why is `$_POST['surveyid']` vulnerable? It is being sanitized by ctype_digit...

Comment: A small note: now your code is okay, but when you grow it, with more variables between that if and the assignation of $table_name, it might become a real problem forgetting why the code is there and if it's validated. I'd suggest doing the validation in the same line as the assignation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you validate that `$_POST['surveyid']` contains at least one digit and contains only digits, your query is safe.

*However,* the `CREATE TABLE` operation that you are trying to do strikes me as a horrible thing to do.  `CREATE TABLE` is a [Data Definition Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) operation, and DDL commands should be executed only in special situations.

Basically, if you routinely create a new table to store responses from each survey, your database schema will be an unmaintainable mess.  I strongly recommend that you post your database schema and describe what you are trying to do in a question to http://dba.stackexchange.com to develop a sane schema that does not require new tables to be created routinely.

Comment: Especially when the table name is a string of digits.  Talk about a non-indicative name!

Answer (score 4):

1. Usually what you need is a `suvery_id` attribute and usage of only one table:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE 'survey_result' (
       `response_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `survey_id` INT NOT NULL,
       `textarea1` TEXT NULL,
       `textarea2` TEXT NULL,
       `textarea3` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
       `drop_down1` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
       `drop_down2` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
       `bool1` BIT NULL,
       `bool2` BIT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`responseid`))';
   ```

   I suppose you'll need proper indexes too (based on your queries).
2. Note that I renamed `responseid` to `response_id` since this format is easier to read (especially if the name contains three or more words).
3. Having indexed column names, like

   > ```
   > `textarea1` TEXT NULL,
   > `textarea2` TEXT NULL,
   > `textarea3` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
   > ```

   does not suggest flexible database schema. Number of input boxes on surveys are likely to change. Here is another design approach on Stack Overflow: [Schema design for when users can define fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/429468/843804), but you can find others, search for *survey system database schema* or something similar. Knowledge about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) also useful.